# Problems passing props withing react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I need to be able to pass a function as props to my 'Tasks' component (see code below), but I can't because of the way I've structured my project. Any tips on how I can change `{taskItems}` to a Tasks instance, so I can pass props from `App.jsx` to `Tasks.jsx`, whilst not breaking the rest of my app?

```js
// App.jsx

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Header from './Header'
import Card from './Card'
import cardData from './cardData'
import Dates from './Dates'
import Tasks from './Tasks'
import Footer from './Footer'


const initialState = [
  {
      id: 8,
      chore: 'wash dishes'
  },
  {
      id: 9,
      chore: 'do laundry'
  },
  {
      id: 10,
      chore: 'clean bathroom'
  }

]

function App() {

  const [taskList, setUpdatedTasks] = useState(initialState)

  const cardComponents = cardData.map(card => {
    return <Card key={card.id} name={card.name} />
  })


  const taskItems = taskList.map(item => {
    console.log(item)
    return <Tasks key={item.id} task={item.chore} />
  })

  const updateHandler = (thing) => {

  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Dates />
      <div className='card-container'>
        {cardComponents}
      </div>
      {taskItems} // how would I change this to an instance of <Tasks/> ?
      <div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737507/6877799) useful to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this question comes from your mindset, ReactJS is not like you think, every component in a ReactJS project is a function and forget about OOP principles. an instance does not make sense here. you can do it as easy as possible, pass your function just like a prop to the `Tasks.jsx` component:

```js
~~~

function App() {

  const [taskList, setUpdatedTasks] = useState(initialState)

  const cardComponents = cardData.map(card => (
    <Card key={card.id} name={card.name} />
  ));


  const taskItems = taskList.map(item => (
      <Tasks
        key={item.id}
        task={item.chore}
        func={setUpdatedTasks} // <--- Here
      />
    );
  });

~~~
```

Comment: thanks, that was super helpful! It's helped my understanding of props a great deal.

Comment: Dear @JoshSimon, you're welcome, I upvote you, and you should know if a post is useful you should accept it by a green tick. it helps others to direct to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

well, TaskItem is another component inside your App and it should receive the function you want to pass to it as props as well, so it will be like this

```
// App.jsx

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Header from './Header'
import Card from './Card'
import cardData from './cardData'
import Dates from './Dates'
import Tasks from './Tasks'
import Footer from './Footer'


const initialState= [
  {
      id: 8,
      chore: 'wash dishes'
  },
  {
      id: 9,
      chore: 'do laundry'
  },
  {
      id: 10,
      chore: 'clean bathroom'
  }

]

function App() {

  const [taskList, setUpdatedTasks] = useState(initialState)

  const cardComponents = cardData.map(card => {
    return <Card key = {card.id} name = {card.name}/>
  })


  const taskItems = ({updateHandler}) =>
taskList.map(item => {
    console.log(item)
    return <Tasks key={item.id} task ={item.chore} updateHandler={updateHandler}/>
  })

  const updateHandler = (thing) => {

  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Dates/>
      <div className = 'card-container'>
        {cardComponents}
      </div>
      {taskItems} **// how would I change this to an instance of <Tasks/> ?**
      <div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```